# How do I get CopyFileEx to report back so I can cancel a file copy operation?

Tags: c#, file-copying

I’m trying to use the `FileUtilities.CopyFile` wrapper for `CopyFileEx` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163851.aspx) . But the `CopyFileCallbackAction` doesn’t get called until after the file is copied (I’ve tried copying a large file). How do I get it to report back so I can cancel the copy if the user so wishes?

EDIT:

See [Why is FileUtilities.CopyFile wrapper for CopyFileEx interfering with winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393336/why-is-fileutilities-copyfile-wrapper-for-copyfileex-interfering-with-winforms)

Comment: `CopyFileCallbackAction` does indeed get called repeatedly during the file copy.

Comment: Can you provide more information? OS, framework version? I find that changing the `CopyFileCallbackAction.Continue` return value in "Callback" to `CopyFileCallbackAction.Cancel` successfully cancels the request after the first iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit to my question (sending to [Why is FileUtilities.CopyFile wrapper for CopyFileEx interfering with winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393336/why-is-fileutilities-copyfile-wrapper-for-copyfileex-interfering-with-winforms)) sends to the answer (by [david-heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)) – I had all on one thread.

EDIT: No. It seems that I had a `this.Update();` missing. See [How can I get code to run after a form is shown? (Trouble with "Shown".)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405254/how-can-i-get-code-to-run-after-a-form-is-shown-trouble-with-shown)  .