# How can I get code to run after a form is shown? (Trouble with "Shown".)

Tags: c#, winforms

I thought `Shown` would be the answer. But it seems that not all controls are equal. A panel *is* shown immediately, while a label – not.

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Panel p = new Panel() { BackColor = Color.Green };
    Label l = new Label() { Text = "abc", Location = new Point(0, 100) };

    public Form2()
    {
        Controls.Add(p);
        Controls.Add(l);

        Shown += new EventHandler(Form2_Shown);
    }

    void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Which, initially, shows this:

[image]

And after 2 seconds - this:

[image]

So how do I run code after "the second image"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following at the beginning of the event handler:

```
this.Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

I think that gets you what you want , but IMHO if you have a lengthy operation you should start another thread.

Comment: The lengthy operation is showing things on the form, so that the user can see them being added.

Comment: You still should do it in another thread.  If you do things in the main UI thread you block the user from doing things like pressing buttons or moving the window around and the window is blocked from doing any updates to it's controls.   For example a file copy in Windows is doing work and updating the UI progress bar, but you can still move the Copy window around.